# How to get records by joining four tables which has multiple condition?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle21c

Scenario:

1. If the ACNO having record in LINK_MASTER then amt will be shared as per below logic

   - From customer table amt column will be shared if acno is in
     cust_fin table has status "2".
   - NPA table amt column will be shared if the acno in cust_fin table
     status has "0" or "1".
2. If the acno not having any record in LINK_MASTER then from customer table amt will be shared.
3. If the flag is 'C' in customer then amt will for this field will be shared as NULL.

Below is DDL and DML for table

```
create table link_master (
    acno varchar2(200)
);

create table custfin (
    status varchar2(200),
    acno varchar2(200)
);

create table npa (
    amt varchar2(200),
    acno varchar2(200)
);

create table customer (
    flag varchar2(200),
    amt varchar2(200)
    acno varchar2(200)
);

insert into link_master values('100');
insert into link_master values('101');
insert into link_master values('102');

insert into custfin values('1','101');
insert into custfin values('2','102');
insert into custfin values('0','100');


insert into npa values('3545','101');
insert into npa values('4566','102');
insert into npa values('4544','108');
insert into npa values('878','109');

insert into customer values('C','123','100');
insert into customer values('O','124','101');
insert into customer values('O','125','102');
insert into customer values('C','126','103');
insert into customer values('C','127','104');
insert into customer values('O','124','102');
```

Expected result:

```
ACNO    STATUS  FLAG    AMT
100      0      C       NULL
101      1      O       4566
102      2      O       4544
103      0      O       126
104             O       127
105             C       NULL
```

I don't need status and flag column in output. Only needed acno and amt. The query need to be in select statement . Because i need to join this query with other queries

Comment: How do you know which NPA table value to take? There are 3 rows with ACNO = 102.

Comment: @Littlefoot . Thanks for correcting mistake . It was copy paste error. Changed now.

Comment: One more thing: why do you have two 102 rows in CUSTOMER table? Also, when is 3) supposed to be taken into account? Only for 2) (no rows in LINK_MASTER), or for all cases?

Comment: Please share your current code and describe what is the issue with it.

Comment: This is not clear to me. Where does account 105 come from in the results? Why do accounts 103 and 104 get the flag 'O', when they have 'C' in the table? And accounts can occur multiple times in the customer tables, as is the case with account 102? Which row's flag and amt would then be considered for the result? (Or is 102 a typo for 105? But then again, why does flag O from the table change into flag C in the results?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use something like:

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT
       c.acno,
       f.status,
       c.flag,
       CASE 
       WHEN c.flag = 'C' THEN NULL
       WHEN l.acno IS NULL OR f.status = 2 THEN c.amt
       WHEN l.acno IS NOT NULL AND f.status IN (0, 1) THEN n.amt
       END AS amt
FROM   customer c
       LEFT OUTER JOIN link_master l
       ON c.acno = l.acno
       LEFT OUTER JOIN custfin f
       ON c.acno = f.acno
       LEFT OUTER JOIN npa n
       ON c.acno = n.acno;
```

Which, for the sample data, outputs:

| ACNO | STATUS | FLAG | AMT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 101 | 1 | O | 3545 |
| 102 | 2 | O | 125 |
| 102 | 2 | O | 124 |
| 100 | 0 | C | *null* |
| 104 | *null* | C | *null* |
| 103 | *null* | C | *null* |

Or, finding the greatest `amt`:

```
SELECT acno,
       status,
       flag,
       amt
FROM   (
  SELECT c.acno,
         f.status,
         c.flag,
         CASE 
         WHEN c.flag = 'C' THEN NULL
         WHEN l.acno IS NULL OR f.status = 2 THEN c.amt
         WHEN l.acno IS NOT NULL AND f.status IN (0, 1) THEN n.amt
         END AS amt,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
           PARTITION BY c.acno
           ORDER BY TO_NUMBER(
               CASE 
               WHEN c.flag = 'C' THEN NULL
               WHEN l.acno IS NULL OR f.status = 2 THEN c.amt
               WHEN l.acno IS NOT NULL AND f.status IN (0, 1) THEN n.amt
               END
             ) DESC
         ) AS rn
  FROM   customer c
         LEFT OUTER JOIN link_master l
         ON c.acno = l.acno
         LEFT OUTER JOIN custfin f
         ON c.acno = f.acno
         LEFT OUTER JOIN npa n
         ON c.acno = n.acno
)
WHERE  rn = 1;
```

Which, for the sample data, outputs:

| ACNO | STATUS | FLAG | AMT |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 100 | 0 | C | *null* |
| 101 | 1 | O | 3545 |
| 102 | 2 | O | 125 |
| 103 | *null* | C | *null* |
| 104 | *null* | C | *null* |

Note: You are not going to get your expected output because:

1. There is no data for `acno = 105` in your sample data.
2. `acno = 101` does not connect to an `amt = 4566`.
3. `acno = 102` has a status of `2` so the `amt` should be from `customer` not `npa`.
4. `acno = 103` has a `flag` of `C` not `O`.

All of these are issues with the input data; fix them and you may be able to get the expected output.

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/nijoV4hZ)

Answer (score 1):

There are some unclear orderings of conditions in your question. The issue is which of 3 instructions affects any other.
For instance,What would you like to get if ACNO 100 has AMT defined in table npa. It exists in link_master table and has status 0 so the starting instruction says to get AMT from npa table, but there is a flag  C that instructs to get Null for AMT. Which one would it be???
Anyway, you need to use CASE expression and that is the main reason  to strictly define the order and interaction between different conditions. CASE expression is sequential, meaning - the first condition satisfied will fetch the value and EXIT CASE. It is crucial to put the conditions in a way/order that will result as you planed.
Below is one option to do it - I put it in a way that some ACNO exists or not in link_master table. If it does then get AMT as described in your point 1. If it doesn't then I choose to combine your points 2 and 3...
First some sample data:

```sql
WITH
    link_master AS
        (   Select To_Char(100 + LEVEL - 1) "ACNO" From Dual Connect By LEVEL <= 3  ),
    custfin AS
        (   Select SubStr(ACNO, -1) "STATUS", ACNO From link_master     ), 
    npa AS
        (   Select '3545' "AMT", '101' "ACNO" From Dual Union All 
            Select '4566' "AMT", '102' "ACNO" From Dual Union All 
            Select '4544' "AMT", '108' "ACNO" From Dual Union All 
            Select '878'  "AMT", '109' "ACNO" From Dual 
        ),
    customer AS
        (   Select 'C' "FLAG", '123' "AMT", '100' "ACNO" From Dual Union All    
            Select 'O' "FLAG", '124' "AMT", '101' "ACNO" From Dual Union All 
            Select 'O' "FLAG", '125' "AMT", '102' "ACNO" From Dual Union All 
            Select 'C' "FLAG", '126' "AMT", '103' "ACNO" From Dual Union All 
            Select 'C' "FLAG", '127' "AMT", '104' "ACNO" From Dual Union All 
            Select 'O' "FLAG", '124' "AMT", '102' "ACNO" From Dual 
        )
```

Here is the code with some comments added

```sql
Select    c.ACNO, cf.STATUS, c.FLAG, 
          CASE WHEN lm.ACNO Is Not Null Then                    -- ACNO IS PRESENT in link_master table
              Case  When cf.STATUS = '2' Then c.AMT                 -- if custfin STATUS is '2'         -> get AMT from customer
                    When cf.STATUS IN('0', '1') Then n.AMT          -- if custfin STATUS is '0' Or '1'  -> get AMT from npa
              Else  Null    --<-- here you can have something else  -- any custfin STATUS that is not IN('0', '1', '2') -> AMT is NULL
              End                                                
          --  ..............    ..............    ................    ....................    ..................    ............................
          ELSE                                                           -- ACNO IS NOT PRESENT in link_master table
              Case  When lm.ACNO Is Null And c.FLAG != 'C' Then c.AMT         -- if customer FLAG is NOT 'C'    -> get AMT from customer
              Else  Null                                                      -- if customer FLAG IS 'C'        -> AMT is NULL
              End 
          END "AMT"
From      customer c
Left Join link_master lm ON(lm.ACNO = c.ACNO)
Left Join custfin cf ON(cf.ACNO = c.ACNO)
Left Join npa n ON(n.ACNO = c.ACNO)
Order By c.ACNO, cf.STATUS 

--  R e s u l t :
--  
--  ACNO STATUS FLAG AMT 
--  ---- ------ ---- ----
--  100  0      C    Null     -> present in link_master, status 0    -> there is no AMT in NPA for ACNO 100
--  101  1      O    3545     -> present in link_master, status 1    -> AMT from npa  -> 3545
--  102  2      O    125      -> present in link_master, status 2    -> AMT from customer  -> 125 (one of two rows for ACNO 102)
--  102  2      O    124      -> present in link_master, status 2    -> AMT from customer  -> 124 (other one of two rows for ACNO 102)
--  103  Null   C    Null     -> not present in link_master, flag C  -> AMT Null
--  104  Null   C    Null     -> not present in link_master, flag C  -> AMT Null
```

Note: Once more, keep in mind that CASE expression is sequential. It is up to you to define the order and strength of conditions and adjust the CASE expressions to get you the result you need.

Answer (score 0):

```
select cst.acno, cstf.status, cst.flag, npa.amt
left join custfin cstf on cst.acno=cstf.acno
left join npa on cst.acno=npa.acno
;
```

I suppose this should do. For this query I do not think I'd need to use the link_master table, seeing that you don't require any column included in that.
And I think you should have primary key link_master_pk on link_master(acno) and foreign keys from the other tables referencing link_master(acno).

Comment: The question states the logic that should be implemented in the initial paragraphs; this answer does not implement any of the desired logic.